# How to change outline color of the dropdown options in a select?

Tags: html, css

How do you change the outline color of the dropdown options in a select?

This is what I currently have:

```css
select:focus{
  outline-color: #986fa5;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

I have tried changing `option:focus` but yet when I click on the select and the dropdown options show up, the options menu has a web-ring colored outline. How do I change that outline color?

Comment: You're pretty limited in what you can do to style select lists. Usually if you want to style them, you should use a plugin that converts it to HTML and allows you to style like a regular element. Here's a popular plugin that will convert the select https://select2.github.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you  want a highly customized select, your best bet is making it by yourself. Here is an example:

```js
$("document").ready(function() {

  $(".option").click(function() {
    $(".option").slideDown();
  });

  $(".option:not(.selected)").click(function() {
    $(".option:not(.selected)").slideUp();
    $(".option.selected").text($(this).text())
    $("#selectVal").val($(this).data("value"))
  });

});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none
}

.option {
  display: none
}

.option:first-child {
  display: block
}

.option:not(.selected):hover {
  background: red
}

#select {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer
}

#select img{width:30px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="select">
  <li class="option selected">--</li>
  <li class="option" data-value="0"><img src="http://www.flags.net/images/largeflags/SPAN0002.GIF" alt=""/>Spain</li>
  <li class="option" data-value="1"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5c/Flag_of_Portugal.svg/255px-Flag_of_Portugal.svg.png" alt=""/>Portugal</li>
</ul>
<input id="selectVal" type="hidden" value="" />
```

It's very easy to understand, and you can get the value as you would get it from a common select. The main difference is that with this approach you can ensure that you will have the same look in all browsers that support `css3`.

Answer (score 0):

The select tag has a default implemented style which will vary between browsers but below is a css solution

```css
#d option:last-child {
  border-bottom: solid red 2px;
  overflow: visible;
}

#d option:first-child {
  border-top: solid red 2px;
}

#d option {
  border-left: solid red 2px;
  border-right: solid red 2px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select id="d">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: The outline red is showing on the drop down menu on firefox 45.3. I cannot say if your browser or browser version supports such styling on the drop down.. what browser are you using?

Comment: ah I see. I'm using chrome